# Adding rows to groups in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have the following Pandas DataFrame:

```
     start_timestamp_milli  end_timestamp_milli       name  rating
1            1555414708025        1555414723279    Valence       2   
2            1555414708025        1555414723279    Arousal       6   
3            1555414708025        1555414723279  Dominance       2   
4            1555414708025        1555414723279    Sadness       1   
5            1555414813304        1555414831795    Valence       3   
6            1555414813304        1555414831795    Arousal       5   
7            1555414813304        1555414831795  Dominance       2   
8            1555414813304        1555414831795    Sadness       1   
9            1555414921819        1555414931382    Valence       1   
10           1555414921819        1555414931382    Arousal       7   
11           1555414921819        1555414931382  Dominance       2   
12           1555414921819        1555414931382    Sadness       1   
13           1555414921819        1555414931382      Anger       1
```

In the above example there are three groups which can be grouped by start_timestamp_milli and end_timestamp_milli. The first group is from index 1 to 4, the second group from index 5 - 8 and the third group from index 9 to 13.

For each such group, if in the name column "Anger" and Happiness" is not present, I would like to insert it with a rating of 0. If it is present, nothing should happen.

The final result should look like this. The added lines are line 5, 6, 11, 12 and 18.

```
     start_timestamp_milli  end_timestamp_milli       name  rating
1            1555414708025        1555414723279    Valence       2   
2            1555414708025        1555414723279    Arousal       6   
3            1555414708025        1555414723279  Dominance       2   
4            1555414708025        1555414723279    Sadness       1
5            1555414708025        1555414723279    Happiness     0
6            1555414708025        1555414723279    Anger         0
7            1555414813304        1555414831795    Valence       3   
8            1555414813304        1555414831795    Arousal       5   
9            1555414813304        1555414831795  Dominance       2   
10           1555414813304        1555414831795    Sadness       1
11           1555414813304        1555414831795    Happiness     0
12           1555414813304        1555414831795    Anger         0   
13           1555414921819        1555414931382    Valence       1   
14           1555414921819        1555414931382    Arousal       7   
15           1555414921819        1555414931382  Dominance       2   
16           1555414921819        1555414931382    Sadness       1 
17           1555414921819        1555414931382   Happiness      0  
18           1555414921819        1555414931382      Anger       1
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Option 1

This very explicitly loops through each group and appends dummy dataframe and drops duplicates.

```
d = dict(name=['Anger', 'Happiness'], rating=0)
cols = ['start_timestamp_milli', 'end_timestamp_milli']
def f(d0, k):
    d1 = pd.DataFrame({**dict(zip(cols, k)), **d})
    return d0.append(d1, ignore_index=True).drop_duplicates('name')

pd.concat([f(d, k) for k, d in df.groupby(cols)], ignore_index=True)

    start_timestamp_milli  end_timestamp_milli       name  rating
0           1555414708025        1555414723279    Valence       2
1           1555414708025        1555414723279    Arousal       6
2           1555414708025        1555414723279  Dominance       2
3           1555414708025        1555414723279    Sadness       1
4           1555414708025        1555414723279      Anger       0
5           1555414708025        1555414723279  Happiness       0
6           1555414813304        1555414831795    Valence       3
7           1555414813304        1555414831795    Arousal       5
8           1555414813304        1555414831795  Dominance       2
9           1555414813304        1555414831795    Sadness       1
10          1555414813304        1555414831795      Anger       0
11          1555414813304        1555414831795  Happiness       0
12          1555414921819        1555414931382    Valence       1
13          1555414921819        1555414931382    Arousal       7
14          1555414921819        1555414931382  Dominance       2
15          1555414921819        1555414931382    Sadness       1
16          1555414921819        1555414931382      Anger       1
17          1555414921819        1555414931382  Happiness       0
```

---

#### Option 2

This builds a new index and uses `reindex`

```
cats = ['Anger', 'Happiness']
cols = ['start_timestamp_milli', 'end_timestamp_milli']

d = df.set_index([*cols, 'name'])
i = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
    [(s, e, n) for s, e in {*zip(*map(df.get, cols))} for n in cats],
    names=d.index.names
) | d.index

df.set_index([*cols, 'name']).reindex(i, fill_value=0).reset_index()

    start_timestamp_milli  end_timestamp_milli       name  rating
0           1555414708025        1555414723279      Anger       0
1           1555414708025        1555414723279    Arousal       6
2           1555414708025        1555414723279  Dominance       2
3           1555414708025        1555414723279  Happiness       0
4           1555414708025        1555414723279    Sadness       1
5           1555414708025        1555414723279    Valence       2
6           1555414813304        1555414831795      Anger       0
7           1555414813304        1555414831795    Arousal       5
8           1555414813304        1555414831795  Dominance       2
9           1555414813304        1555414831795  Happiness       0
10          1555414813304        1555414831795    Sadness       1
11          1555414813304        1555414831795    Valence       3
12          1555414921819        1555414931382      Anger       1
13          1555414921819        1555414931382    Arousal       7
14          1555414921819        1555414931382  Dominance       2
15          1555414921819        1555414931382  Happiness       0
16          1555414921819        1555414931382    Sadness       1
17          1555414921819        1555414931382    Valence       1
```

Comment: The difference between mine and [@WeNYoBen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56062393/2336654) is that their answer will add zero for every unique value in `name` for each grouping of start and end.  This may be what the OP wanted but did not explicitly say.  I intentionally went through extra trouble to ensure that I only added `'Anger'` and `'Happiness'` if they didn't exist for a group.  OP and any future readers, please choose according to your needs.

Comment: Your approach worked well. I would like to add another row to each grouping of start and end. Namely a row with name "Neutral". The rating column of the "Neutral" row should be 1 if Anger and Sadness have a rating of 0 and 0 otherwise. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

I am using `unstack` + `stack` + `reindex`

```
s=set(df.name.unique().tolist()+['Anger','Happiness'])

df.set_index(df.columns[:-1].tolist()).rating.\
    unstack(fill_value=0).\
       reindex(columns=s,fill_value=0).\ 
           stack().reset_index()
```

Comment: This almost works, add a `.drop_duplicates().reset_index()` to get the desired output

Comment: @Vink thank you , i think using set is slightly better than drop_duplicate

Comment: agreed, safer & more precise